# Union type signatures get "merged" (intersected) unexpectedly

Tags: typescript, union-types

I'm trying to write a signature for a function that either:

- accepts a `string`
- accepts an object with a property of `string` and a optional formatter of `string => string`
- accepts an object with a property of `string[]` and a optional formatter of `string[] => string`

```
type NameFormatter<T> = {
  name: T;
  formatter? : (value?: T) => string;
}

type Props = {
    initials: string | (NameFormatter<string> | NameFormatter<Array<string>>)
}


function getInitials(props: Props) {
    const initials = props.initials;

    if(typeof initials === 'string') return initials;
    if(initials.formatter) return initials.formatter(initials.name);
    return initials.name;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgWwgMQPYCcF2MC6A8AKgHxQC8UA3gFBRQB2iEAXFIQNy1QBmGWOeAPxRWACgBucADYBXCINaEAlOVIBnYOgCW9AOacAvtWqhIUAArpUYNeSpc6OrcC3S1rDdr1QAPlFHwSGiY2LgEnjq6pH6BKHyhePgAgujocCD4EXrExErURsbcMvQAxi6o9FC6EMAAkvTOrlJqomBWNqyW1moqNHR0JRUaUE4ubnZt3QB0o01qnA4j3KKmEKjcIw1jzeRkFADkWbr7Kug1MuiVs26c-Uui181TvCEC6Kfnl5uNbs-xbw8tnMpowkEpbv0zsALlcgb9QRBDEA)

I would expect this to work as the `name/formatter` pairs can only be constructed in a way in which they are compatible.

Instead I get an error when I try to pass name into the formatter:

> Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(string & string[]) | undefined'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(string & string[]) | undefined'.

I'm confused why the formatter signature has become an intersection of `string & string[]`?

Maybe I'm just going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: I'm guessing there's some algebraic reason this is happening...

Comment: TypeScript doesn't really support "correlated union types" as mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581); you will probably want to use a type assertion and move on (as the alternative is to use redundant code).

Comment: See the answer to the question this duplicates, and definitely see microsoft/TypeScript#30581 linked above since its `UnionRecord` type is close to what you're doing here (and you can also see the growing list of SO questions pertaining to it).  If I translate the answer from that question here, I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/N7b7rw).  I'd recommend using a type assertion to suppress the error.

Comment: @jcalz haha the redundant solution is very "meta"

`isStringNameFormatter(initials) ? initials.formatter(initials.name) : initials.formatter(initials.name)`

Thanks for the info!

Comment: @NSjonas this article may help you to understand better whats going on here https://catchts.com/react-props